# What happens if a character, under the influence of the jump spell, tries to jump into an antimagic field?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, antimagic-field

Say a character with 20 strength has the [jump](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/jump) spell cast upon them. On the other side of a 40 foot chasm is an enemy standing next to the ledge. The character takes a 10 foot run up and leaps over the chasm, planning to land next to the enemy. Unbeknownst to them however, the enemy is a spell caster who has cast [antimagic field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) previously.

The characters strength score, jump spell and the 10 foot run up they took means they can jump 60 feet. However, they will find themselves in the area of effect of an antimagic field when they are still 10 feet from the other side of the ledge.

So what happens? Do they immediately stop all forward movement when they enter the field and drop down into the chasm because the jump spell has been suppressed? Or does the antimagic field have no effect because their jump distance was determined when they took off (ie. because physics)?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Theory crafting.

Comment: Does this character actually have the required 70 foot speed to make the jump?

Comment: @Medix2 Assuming the use of the Dash action, there are several ways to achieve a speed of 70 feet in a turn, and the Mobile feat is the most easy solution to theorycraft with.

Comment: I would think just being a wood elf and using Dash is the *easiest* solution.

Comment: Side note: I never realized before that *Jump* has a 1-minute duration. For some reason I had it in my head that the spell worked for a single jump per casting.

Answer (score 17):

### [Jump](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jump)

*to push yourself suddenly off the ground in order to go over something*

When your feet leave the ground you have jumped - that is, you have done the thing that the Jump spell is enhancing. When you enter the Antimagic Field the Jump spell ceases to operate so if you were to jump now, you would not get its benefit. This would not affect the motion that you already had.

Comment: In this case, _jump_, is the name of the spell and has a [specific in game definition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/jump).  So use of the vernacular doesn't apply.

Comment: @GcL no, the jump was *not* affected by the Anti Magic field when the character jumped.  They can't jump a second time, though, once they arrive.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I think that is a reasonable interpretation, and would be more willing to buy it if the duration were instantaneous.  To my reading, the additional distance is imparted by the ongoing effect of the spell.  Similarly to other kinds of movement such as flying.  A character doesn't get to fly through antimagic and just "can't fly a second time"

Comment: @GcL AMF is already OP, I don't like giving it extra powers - Jump is a form of movement, PCs with  higher movement also jump farther. What happens when they land is another matter.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I would expect most 8th level spells to be rather powerful.  Fly is another form of movement.  PCs with wings can fly further.  When the additional movement is granted by an ongoing spell effect, it is suppressed when in an AMF.

Comment: @GcL: Concerns about duration vs instantaneous would only make sense if you're going to argue that the spell's duration could end in the middle of your jump, thereby making it fail. I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE That could happen if someone were holding an action to cast dispel magic on the character when then reached some point (e.g. jumping or flying across a chasm)

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR: DM call, I'd rule that the character crosses the chasm.**

---

Let us start from the rules, citing the relevant excerpts:

**Jumping**

> **Long Jump.** When you make a long jump, you cover a number of feet up to your Strength score if you move at least 10 feet on foot immediately before the jump. [...] Either way, each foot you clear on the jump costs a foot of movement.

**Jump Spell**

> **Components**: V, S, M (a grasshopper's hind leg)
> **Duration**: 1 min.
>
> You touch a creature. The creature’s jump distance is tripled until the spell ends.

And... this is it. There is strictly no ruling about interaction with AMF.

---

*There is an important little nugget, still: "each foot your clear on the jump costs a foot of movement". So 10 ft. of sprinting plus 60 ft. of jumping still requires 70 ft. of movement. A character may be able to Dash (Action) to gain the required feet of movement.*

---

So, assuming the character has the necessary movement available, it's up to the DM really since the rules just don't say.

*Personally*, I would take the component as a hint from the designers: a "grasshoper's hind leg" works by generating a strong impulse at the start of the jump, not by making the grasshoper lighter during the jump, and therefore I'd argue that the effect of the spell's boost is instantaneous at the moment of impulse, and from then it's a pure ballistic trajectory.

That's my interpretation, though, and it may have implications: character gets higher (may hit the ceiling), character pushes stronger (may break rotting floor), ...

Answer (score 3):

### **The Jump is Completed, no further enhanced jumps are effective**

The jump action has already been completed. The legs extended, the body pushed into motion with enhanced force during the action. Even though the spell is suppressed, the kinetic energy has already been established, and the motion continues.

Look at the spell component: A grasshopper's leg. If a grasshopper were to jump, and then his legs were to fall off mid-air, he lost the method of his locomotion, but he wouldn't immediately drop straight down. He already started his jump, he's already moving forward at a certain rate. He'll land where originally intended (maybe even a little further now that he's lost some wind resistance from those huge legs).

The earlier example of a fly spell being anti-magic'd is not relevant. The fly spell itself is providing a constant form of locomotion and allowing direction change, altitude change, etc. It is consistently protecting the recipient from gravity. If it was anti-magic'd (is that a term?) the user would cease to be held aloft by the spell, and physics would take over. If they were merely "hovering", they would fall straight down. If they were flying in a straight line, they would continue their forward momentum as they fell.

At the end of the day, it's your call, of course. Look at the presented answers and see which makes the most sense to you and go with it. It's not a matter of life or death. This is 5e. Falls are meaningless.

Comment: Potentially ending prone isnt meaningless

Comment: And depending on your class and level, a far enough fall could kill you (although if you're facing someone with AMF, you've probably got a high level). And finding yourself separated from the party could be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

## The effect of *jump* is suppressed, and the character does not make it.

The effect of "creature's jump distance is tripled" is suppressed in the field.

> Any active spell or other magical effect on a creature or an object in the sphere is suppressed while the creature or object is in it

Upon entry into the field, the character no longer has the benefit of the extra jump distance.  Their remaining jump distance is zero, and they drop.

Furthermore, the effect of *antimagic-field* goes on to specify that magic even higher level than *jump* or *fly* such as *teleportation* and *planar travel* are unable to move an affected creature within the sphere.

Comment: Once they fall out of the field, will Jump turn on again and propel them into the chasm wall Wile E Coyote style, or will the remaining jump distance be zero?

Comment: @JoelHarmon I'm entertained by that thought.  Having remaining move drop to 0 mid-air means they're going to be immediately falling.  Once falling, remaining jump distance can't be used... so just down to the canyon floor with ol' Mr. Coyote.

Comment: That's a bit like saying that the effects of heal are reverted when walking through the anti-magic field.... and all the old wounds would reopen.

Comment: @UKMonkey The jump distance is explicitly increased *"until the spell ends"*. You can not compare it to an instantaneous spell effect, which has no duration specified. Try comparing to a spell like *False Life* for a valid comparison.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir I think it would be far more reasonable to say that the character needs to make a dex roll or something to succeed the landing - because the character is already in the air.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir as for your comparison - if the character were to jump into the field with false life - would you let them land where they intended; even if they died mid jump?  I think I would.

Comment: @UKMonkey I'm not talking about what's a reasonable ruling, just mentioning that from the AMF point of view, *Jump* and healing spells are very different. (On the matter of *Jump* in AMF, I'd go with "well, it does not affect other athletic stuff, so it sounds more like an antigrav/levitate kind of effect only active during jump, and not some STR boost". YMMV.)

Answer (score 1):

Jump, unlike fly, is initiated, but does not continue to apply it's effect. You cannot jump, fly, teleport, or other magically enhanced or created movement while "in the AMF", because the AMF suppresses magic (hence Anti=Magic). This would not apply to a person who has already jumped, as the magic effect has already occurred.

Would a heat-seeking missile suddenly not fly because the heat source was turned off? No. It would go where it was last heading. It may miss the mark and not detonate where it was intended.

Something to consider, however, is how much protection the jump spell gives the jumper when they land? If the spell allows the person to land without taking any damage, then once they reach the AMF, then all bets are off on the landing. Jumping 70 feet without sustaining any damage? I would have them roll for damage and see what happens there. Also, as they are taking damage (up to 20D6), it will most certainly do something to their initiative and maybe their movement base. I you aimed it right, you would crash into the other MU and you should roll for dex and damage for the MU then.

How about using catapult spell and heft your largest fighter over?

Comment: Catapult only throws an object that weighs 1-5 pounds. I suppose, somehow, you might have a fighter within that weight range.